# Select case if <0 then '0'

Tags: sql, oracle, case, sql-insert

Looking for a bit of guidance here. I've got a query performing a balance calculation that is also being formatted for display on a letter we've got going out. I'm looking to display 0 if Total_Billable - Annual_Sum <0. Basically, I want to avoid showing negative numbers for cleanliness. See below:

```
select TO_CHAR(NVL(:TOTAL_BILLABLE2 - :ANNUAL_SUM2,0),'$999,990')<br>
       into :REMAINING_BALANCE <br>
FROM SPRIDEN <br>
 where SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID = :Student_ID
```

I feel like I'm VASTLY overthinking where to place my CASE statement, but this is my first go round using variables to calculate a stored value in another variable. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Because of the [NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) used, you should add a tag for `Oracle`.   (Use [edit] go to the **Tags**, and add the tag....)     P.S. When you are not working with Oracle, please change it to the correct tag!

Comment: Replace `NVL(:TOTAL_BILLABLE2 - :ANNUAL_SUM2,0)` with `GREATEST(NVL(:TOTAL_BILLABLE2 - :ANNUAL_SUM2,0), 0)`? That will use the greater of the two values, so if the calculated balance is < 0, the value used will be 0 (because it is greater than the negative number).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [CASE WHEN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96):

```
select TO_CHAR(CASE WHEN :TOTAL_BILLABLE2 - :ANNUAL_SUM2<0 
                    THEN 0 
                    ELSE :TOTAL_BILLABLE2 - :ANNUAL_SUM2 END,'$999,990')
       into :REMAINING_BALANCE 
FROM SPRIDEN 
 where SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID = :Student_ID
```

Comment: Fantastic!
This absolutely nailed it. Completely overthinking placement, but this did the trick. Thank you for your speedy response!
And, all, I apologize for not tagging Oracle! Long time lurker, first time poster, here. I'll do better next time.